# Jags for finite mixture model with two different parametric distribution

Tags: jags, winbugs, rjags

> > I am having a problem running a finite mixture model with two
> > different parametric distributions. I am getting this error
> >
> > Error in jags.model(textConnection(mod1_string), data = data1_jags,
> > inits = inits1,  :    Error in node Ones[1] Invalid parent values
> >
> > ## Define the JAGS model mod1_string <- " model {   for (i in 1:n) {
>
> ```
> # first distribution: the negative binomial part
> y_nb[i] ~ dnegbin(prob[i], phi)
> prob[i] <- phi / (phi + eps[i] * mu[i])
> log(mu[i]) <- b1[V[i]] * x6[i] + b2[V[i]] * x28[i]
> eps[i] ~ dgamma(f[i], t[V[i]])
> f[i] <- 1 + z[i] 
> z[i] ~ dbern(k[V[i]])
> V[i] ~ dcat(W[])
>
> # second distribution: Poisson
> y_pois[i] ~ dpois(mu2[i])
> mu2[i] <- b1[P[i]] * x6[i] + b2[P[i]] * x28[i]
> P[i] ~ dcat(W[])
>
> # The latent class part using dcat
> component_chosen[i] ~ dcat(probs)
>
> # Define ld_comp
> ld_comp[i, 1] <- y_nb[i]
> ld_comp[i, 2] <- y_pois[i]
>
> # Select one of these two densities and normalize with a Constant
> density[i] <- exp(ld_comp[i, component_chosen[i]])
>
> # Ones node
> Ones[i] ~ dbern(density[i])
>
>    }
> ```
>
> for (j in 1:2) {
> # Priors
> b1[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
> b2[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
> k[j] ~ dunif(0, 1)
> t[j] <- (1 - k[j]) / k[j]
> mean.eps[j] <- (t[j] + 2) / (t[j] * (t[j] + 1))
> log.mean.eps[j] <- log(mean.eps[j])
> }
>
> ```
> # Priors for 2 parameters using a dirichlet distribution
> #probs ~ ddirch(c(1, 1))
> probs~ ddirch(c(1, 1))
> ```
>
> ## Priors for W
>
> ```
>  W[1] ~ dunif(0, 1)   W[2] <- 1 - W[1]
>  # Prior for phi   phi ~ dgamma(0.1, 0.1)
> ```
>
> }"
>
> ## Set seed and prepare data set.seed(72)
>
> data1_jags <- list(y_nb = y,y_pois=y, n = nrow(data), x6 = x6, x28 =
> x28)
>
> params1 <- c("b1", "b2", "k", "phi")
>
> ## Define initial values inits1 <- function() {   inits <- list("b1" = c(0, 0), "b2" = c(0, 0), "k" = c(0.1, 0.5), "phi" = 5) }
>
> ## Create the JAGS model mod1 <- jags.model(textConnection(mod1_string), data = data1_jags, inits =
>
> inits1, n.chains = 3)
>
> ## Update the model update(mod1, 1000)
>
> ## Run the model mod1_sim <- coda.samples(model = mod1, variable.names = params1, n.iter = 5e3, n.thin = 50)
>
> ## Combine the chains mod1_csim <- do.call(rbind, mod1_sim)
>
> ## Model checking
>
> ## Convergence diagnostics par(mar = c(3, 3, 1, 1))  # Set smaller margins (bottom, left, top, right) plot(mod1_sim)
>
> gelman.diag(mod1_sim) autocorr.diag(mod1_sim) effectiveSize(mod1_sim)
> summary(mod1_sim) acf(mod1_csim, lag.max = 100)
>
> ## Define the JAGS model mod1_string <- " model {   for (i in 1:n) {
>
> ```
> # first distribution: the negative binomial part
> y_nb[i] ~ dnegbin(prob[i], phi)
> prob[i] <- phi / (phi + eps[i] * mu[i])
> log(mu[i]) <- b1[V[i]] * x6[i] + b2[V[i]] * x28[i]
> eps[i] ~ dgamma(f[i], t[V[i]])
> f[i] <- 1 + z[i] 
> z[i] ~ dbern(k[V[i]])
> V[i] ~ dcat(W[])
>
> # second distribution: Poisson
> y_pois[i] ~ dpois(mu2[i])
> mu2[i] <- b1[P[i]] * x6[i] + b2[P[i]] * x28[i]
> P[i] ~ dcat(W[])
>
> # The latent class part using dcat
> component_chosen[i] ~ dcat(probs)
>
> # Define ld_comp
> ld_comp[i, 1] <- y_nb[i]
> ld_comp[i, 2] <- y_pois[i]
>
> # Select one of these two densities and normalize with a Constant
> density[i] <- exp(ld_comp[i, component_chosen[i]])
>
> # Ones node
> Ones[i] ~ dbern(density[i])   }
> ```
>
> for (j in 1:2) {
> # Priors
> b1[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
> b2[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
> k[j] ~ dunif(0, 1)
> t[j] <- (1 - k[j]) / k[j]
> mean.eps[j] <- (t[j] + 2) / (t[j] * (t[j] + 1))
> log.mean.eps[j] <- log(mean.eps[j])
> }
>
> ```
> # Priors for 2 parameters using a dirichlet distribution
> #probs ~ ddirch(c(1, 1))
> probs~ ddirch(c(1, 1))
> ```
>
> ## Priors for W
>
> ```
>  W[1] ~ dunif(0, 1)   W[2] <- 1 - W[1]
>  # Prior for phi   phi ~ dgamma(0.1, 0.1)
> ```
>
> }"
>
> ## Set seed and prepare data set.seed(72)
>
> data1_jags <- list(y_nb = y,y_pois=y, n = nrow(data), x6 = x6, x28 =
> x28)
>
> params1 <- c("b1", "b2", "k", "phi")
>
> ## Define initial values inits1 <- function() {   inits <- list("b1" = c(0, 0), "b2" = c(0, 0), "k" = c(0.1, 0.5), "phi" = 5) }
>
> ## Create the JAGS model mod1 <- jags.model(textConnection(mod1_string), data = data1_jags, inits =
>
> inits1, n.chains = 3)
>
> ## Update the model update(mod1, 1000)
>
> ## Run the model mod1_sim <- coda.samples(model = mod1, variable.names = params1, n.iter = 5e3, n.thin = 50)
>
> ## Combine the chains mod1_csim <- do.call(rbind, mod1_sim)
>
> ## Model checking
>
> ## Convergence diagnostics par(mar = c(3, 3, 1, 1))  # Set smaller margins (bottom, left, top, right) plot(mod1_sim)
>
> gelman.diag(mod1_sim) autocorr.diag(mod1_sim) effectiveSize(mod1_sim)
> summary(mod1_sim) acf(mod1_csim, lag.max = 100)

Comment: Hard to say without your data, but it looks like you're calling `y=data$y`, in the data list (which makes it look like a vector) and in your code, you have it as a two-column matrix.  That could produce this error.